# Pointer by reference on templates and normal functions

Tags: c++

Here is my code :

```
#include <iostream>


template<typename B>
class test{
    public:
    B* t;

    test(const B& init){
    }   
};



void funct(const int*& test){

}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    test<int*> t(new int(2));   // works fine
    funct(new int(2));          //error

    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to emulate what's happening on my templated class, but somehow i get errors. I believe that `const B& init` with B as `int*` will be `const int*& init`. Adding const allowed it to accept temporary "new"s. I made a non-templated function to test it and it has this header, `void funct(const int*& test)`. It is just the same as above but how come it wont take `new int(2)` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`const int*&` means "reference to pointer to `const int`. You need the `const` to apply to the *pointer*, not to the `int`:

```
void funct(int* const& test){}
```

This is what the template version does. `T` is a pointer to `int`, so `T&` is really a reference to pointer to `int`. The template does not perform a textual substitution of `T` for `int*`. It substitutes the *type*. You'd get the same if you used `typedef int* X` and `const X&`.

Comment: Ahhh i see. i thought they get substituted directly.